# What other UIWindow receiving touch events is the Apple docs talking about?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, event-handling, uiwindow

The [Apple docs on windows](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/WindowScreenRolesinApp/WindowScreenRolesinApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555-CH4-SW8) say:

> A window is considered the key window when it is currently receiving keyboard and non touch-related events. Whereas touch events are delivered to the window in which the touch occurred, events that don’t have an associated coordinate value are delivered to the key window. Only one window at a time can be key.

This means that the default window that Xcode provides us is the key window by default, but then our button taps are listened to by any other window which is not a key window. Which window is this, which is listening to the touch events? We do not generally add any other window. So from where did this window come?

Answer (score 0):

`UIWindow` is just a `UIView` subclass that doesn't need to be added to any existing view hierarchy.  While there's only one by default in an iOS application, it's not uncommon to use `UIWindow` instances for things like status bar overlays and full-screen overlays.